# Is there any documentation for the `NSEventTypeSystemDefined ` `NSEvent`?

Tags: macos, cocoa, documentation, nsevent

Apple provides https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nseventtype/nseventtypesystemdefined?language=objc

This page says nothing more than:

> No overview available.
>   Declaration:
>       NSEventTypeSystemDefined = 14

Comment: Not much help but see NSEvent.h and the deprecated `NSSystemDefined`, "The remaining event types—NSAppKitDefined, NSSystemDefined, and NSApplicationDefined—are less structured, containing only generic subtype and data fields. Of these three miscellaneous event types, only NSApplicationDefined is of real use to application programs.". What do you want to know?

Comment: See also `-[NSEvent otherEventWithType:location:modifierFlags:timestamp:windowNumber:context:subtype:data1:data2:]`, "type: One of the following event-type constants: NSAppKitDefined, NSSystemDefined, NSApplicationDefined, NSPeriodic. Your code should only create events of type NSApplicationDefined."

Comment: Specifically I'm trying to intercept (maybe eat) and inject mouse and keyboard events. I notice Left Mouse Down generates a `NSEventTypeSystemDefined` with `data1:1, data2:1, subtype 7`, Up gives `data2:0`. So if I create my own mouse events, should I recreate these?  I'm currently not doing so, and everything seems to be working.

Comment: Also, I'm trying to catch+eat CAPSLOCK, which must be one of the hardest keys on the keyboard. That generates a `subtype:d3`, But if I plug in an external keyboard I'm able to get more exotic events. I'm considering an alternative plan where I watch the raw key up/down event at the IOHID layer (nice and clean, only I don't seem to be able to eat it), and then eat the associated events using an event-tap.